# Allow only two digits after decimal in javascript

Tags: .net, javascript

I have a variable i=28.57142857142857;
I want to alert(i); alert this variable on user screen. But I want only two digits after decimal. i.e **28.57**

How to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using toFixed:

```
 alert(i.toFixed(2));
```

If you need the precision mentioned in the next answer from [Jappie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317440/jappie), you could overwrite the native toFixed method like this:

```
Number.prototype.toFixed = function (precision) {
 var power = Math.pow(10, precision || 0);
 return String(Math.round(this * power) / power);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
alert(Math.round(i * 100) / 100);
```

There are problems with toFixed. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661562/how-to-format-a-float-in-javascript/661757#661757).

Answer (score 0):

100% working!!!!

```html
<html>
     <head>
      <script>
      function replacePonto(){
        var input = document.getElementById('qtd');
        var ponto = input.value.split('.').length;
        var slash = input.value.split('-').length;
        if (ponto > 2)
                input.value=input.value.substr(0,(input.value.length)-1);

        if(slash > 2)
                input.value=input.value.substr(0,(input.value.length)-1);

        input.value=input.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/,'');

        if (ponto ==2)
 input.value=input.value.substr(0,(input.value.indexOf('.')+3));

if(input.value == '.')
 input.value = "";
              }
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
         <input type="text" id="qtd" maxlength="10" style="width:140px" onkeyup="return replacePonto()">
      </body>
    </html>
```