# Trying to format number to 2 decimal places jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, number-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: formatting number with exactly two decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals)

Getting a bit muddled up using variables and now cant seem to get calculation to work at all!?

```
 $("#discount").change(function(){
            var list = $("#list").val();
            var discount = $("#discount").val();
            var price = $("#price");
            var temp = discount * list;
            var temp1 = list - temp;
            var total = parseFloat($(this).temp1()).toFixed(2);

            price.val(total);       
 });
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`$(this).temp1()` looks particularly out of place, I think you just meant to use the `temp1` variable.  Since it's already a number, you don't need to use `parseFloat` on it either:

```
$("#discount").change(function() {
    var list = $("#list").val();
    var discount = $("#discount").val();
    var price = $("#price");
    var temp = discount * list;
    var temp1 = list - temp;
    var total = temp1.toFixed(2);

    price.val(total);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you to convert strings to number first before calculation. For example,

```
var list = parseFloat($("#list").val());
var discount = parseFloat($("#discount").val());
var price = $("#price");
var total = list - (discount * list);
price.val(total.toFixed(2));
```

Also, if discount is in percentage (for example, say 25) then you have to divide by 100 i.e. `list - (discount/100 * list)`

BTW, refer this SO thread where people had warned against ToFixed usage: [How to format a float in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661562/how-to-format-a-float-in-javascript)

Comment: Should be total.toFixed(2) not total.ToFixed(2)