# formatting decimals in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, format

i want to format a number to max of 2 decimals in javascript.  i see that there is:

```
toFixed(2)
```

but this seems like it would ALWAYS do 2 decimals.  i want something that would take:  100.1223334 and convert it to 100.12 but i want this function to convert 100.5 to just 100.5 (since < 2 decimal digits)

whats is the best way of doing this in javascript.

Comment: look at similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661562/how-to-format-a-float-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Math.round(number * 100) / 100`.

For example, 100.1223 becomes 10012.23, which is rounded to the nearest integer (10012) and then divided by 100 to get 100.12.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.round(number)`. This will round off the number to maximum 2 decimals.

Comment: No, it will round it to the nearest integer; no digits after the decimal point.

Comment: True, my mistake, confused it with .net round method.