# Variable is different when using it directly

Tags: javascript, floating-point

The Javascript engine of Google Chrome does something strange with the variable values in this prototype.

The prototype is defined with:

```
function matrix4def()
{
 this.m00=0;
 this.m01=0;
 this.m02=0;
 this.m03=0;
 this.m10=0;
 this.m11=0;
 this.m12=0;
 this.m13=0;
 this.m20=0;
 this.m21=0;
 this.m22=0;
 this.m23=0;
 this.m30=0;
 this.m31=0;
 this.m32=0;
 this.m33=0;
};

var value = new matrix4def();
```

`console.log(value)` shows us:

```
 m00: 1
 m01: 0
 m02: 0
 m03: 0
 m10: 0
 m11: 1
 m12: 0
 m13: 0
 m20: 0
 m21: 0
 m22: 1
 m23: 0
 m30: 0
 m31: 0
 m32: 0
 m33: 1
```

While using `console.log(value.m00)` will show us: `-6.123031769111886e-17`.
Doing `console.log(value); console.log(value.m00); console.log(value);` shows no difference between the first and second call of `console.log(value);`.

Doing `console.log(typeof(value.m00))` will show us: `number`

I've tried doing `parseFloat(value.m00)`, but that didn't show 1 either...
Storing the value of `value.m00` to a temporary value shows me `-6.123031769111886e-17` too.

Does anyone have a clue what's happening here?

P.S.: I cannot show you the entire code; it's part of render code that does a lot with these values.

Comment: I don't see this happending. How are you creating your object "value"?

Comment: `var value = new matrix4def();` I must say that it works on all internal calculations, but when you try to see the actual result, you get wrong info.

Comment: Floats and integers are both of the type `number` in JavaScript, just FYI.

Comment: You should really use a (twodimensional?) array

Comment: This code does indeed work, but there's a problem with the 'transfer to text' code of either the Javascript engine. I wonder why that happens.

Comment: @Bergi It would be too complicated to change this code to a twodimensional array, as the variables are used almost everywhere.

Comment: @Diamondo25: It will just become a pain if you need to change it to `matrix5def` or the like…

Comment: What input goes to the `parseFloat` call? I don't really see the need to do text-to-number conversion.

Comment: @Bergi We won't use matrix5 or any other matrix definition.

Comment: @IanKuca The value of `value.m00`.

Comment: But that is already a number, isn't it?

Comment: @IanKuca typeof(value.m00) shows me that it's a number, yes.

Comment: Then any conversion (parseFloat) is useless because `parseFloat(value) === value` in your case. I don't really see your issue.

Comment: @IanKuca It was a try to force it to be a correct value, as I thought it might've been a different type of value.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an issue with `console.log`, which show you the current property values of an object instead of the ones it had when the object was logged. Do you have any code around (after) the logging that changes the values?

```
console.log(new matrix4def().m00)
```

*will* log `0`, not something negative very close to zero.

Comment: I'm agree with you, becourse in my demo, it's running well, and dosen't have some strange result

Comment: The `console.log` is ran with the final values of `value`, that will be used to render the objects in WebGL.

Comment: Does the WebGL code change the values? Show it to us, create a http://jsfiddle.net for it.

Comment: @Bergi Running `console.log(value); console.log(value.m00); console.log(value);` shows me that, internally, `value.m00` is not changed at all, but `console.log(value.m00)` still shows me the `-6.123...`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you encounter this issue when running your full script (or at least: after performing some operations on the properties of your object). And, given that you're using `parseFloat`, I'm assuming the values can be decimal (float) values. 
If that's the case, you should take a closer look at the known issues with JS and floating point numbers:

[either here](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic2.html)
[or here](http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/Floating-Point-And-Javascript.htm)
[maybe here, too](http://ajaxian.com/archives/crock-on-floating-points-in-javascript)
[and last but not least: here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem)

Don't forget to look into the articles that are referred to on the last page

Comment: I've tried using `console.log(value.m00.toFixed(5));`, but it gives me `-0.00000` O.o. Using `console.log(value.m00.toPrecision(5));` gives `-6.1230e-17`

Comment: `toFixed` has [issues, too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661562/how-to-format-a-float-in-javascript/661757#661757). If needs must, you can use Christophe's generic `toFixed` function, and attach that to the `Number.prototype`. That should work

Comment: The `toFixed` function returns '0' :(

Comment: Nope, it should've returned '1'

Comment: Weird, `parseFloat(value.m00.toFixed(5)).toPrecision(5);`? _desparate, I know_, but returns 0.00000 here