# How do I round only floating digit in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I have a javacript output 14.85 now 
i want to make it 14.90 for 14.85
and for 14.84 i need it to 14.80,
Is it possible ?

thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round (Example: Decimal rounding)

Comment: check the answer for that question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661562/how-to-format-a-float-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
var number = Math.round(14.85 * 10) / 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that produces the exact result what you need:

```
function roundFloat(n) {
    return (Math.round(n * 10) / 10).toFixed(2);
}

roundFloat(14.84);  // "14.80"
roundFloat(14.85);  // "14.90"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newNumber = (Math.round(oldNumber*10)/10).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Please provide a reason for downvote.