# In ClojureScript, how to display a float with 2 decimals?

Tags: clojurescript

I have tried to use `with-precision` but it didn't work:

```
(.log js/console (with-precision 2 1.2345))
```

So I have used `toFixed`:

```
(.log js/console (.toFixed 1.2345 2))
```

But I feel it's not the idiomatic way of doing that.

In addition, I don't understand why `with-precision` doesn't work.

Please inspire me...

Comment: there is no with-precision in cljs

Comment: @edbond, how do I know what parts of `clojure` are available in `cljs`?

Comment: some info here - https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure Also pay attention to warnings: `WARNING: Use of undeclared Var some-namespace/with-precision at line 430`

Answer (score 17):

```
(ns foo.bar
  (:require
    [goog.string :as gstring]
    [goog.string.format]))

(.log js/console (gstring/format "%.2f" 1.2345))
```

Comment: Interestingly Google Closure [specifically says](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.string.format.html) to use `.toFixed` in simple cases!

Comment: Yes, I think `.toFixed` is better for this example. The correct answer seems to be "you are doing it right" :)

Answer (score 11):

```
(ns foo.bar
  (:require [cljs.pprint :as pprint]))

(pprint/cl-format nil  "~,2f" 1.2345) ; => returns "1.23"
(pprint/cl-format true "~,2f" 1.2345) ; => prints "1.23", returns nil
```

Same code could be used in Clojure if you swap `cljs.pprint` with `clojure.pprint`.

Answer (score 3):

```
(defn round-number 
   [f]
   (/ (.round js/Math (* 100 f)) 100))
```

If you want to keep it as number type (inspired by [javascript reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661562/how-to-format-a-float-in-javascript))