# How to format floating numbers to string without unnecessary decimal 0?

Tags: javascript

javascript. How to nicely format floating numbers to string without unnecessary decimal 0?

Here's an example input:

- 12.000
- 12.354
- 12.340
- 12.700

What I want is:

- 12
- 12.354
- 12.34
- 12.7

Comment: How do you currently *format* ? You should not have any 0 unless you add them.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do here? Round to 3 d.p. but only display those d.p. if they are non-zero? If the input was `12.3545` what would you expect the output to be? Are you inputs really numbers? Or are they strings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a float in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661562/how-to-format-a-float-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parseFloat` - it will take care of any floating `0`

```
alert(parseFloat("12.00")); //12
```

Comment: There's no need to use parseFloat on floating point numbers.