# How to format float?

Tags: javascript

I have float numbers:

```
var a = parseFloat("12.999");
var b = parseFloat("14");
```

And I want to display them as:

```
12.99
14.00 -> with zeros
```

But without round, only truncate. How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a float in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661562/how-to-format-a-float-in-javascript)

Comment: Not really a duplicate, since this involves truncating and not rounding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use a combination of the `Math.floor()` and `Number.prototype.toFixed()` function, [like this](http://atornblad.se/formatting-a-truncated-float-javascript):

```
console.log((Math.floor(a * 100) * 0.01).toFixed(2));
console.log((Math.floor(b * 100) * 0.01).toFixed(2));
```

[Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) will truncate the value to the closest lower integer. That is why you need to first multiply by 100 and then multiply by 0.01.

[Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) will format your output using a set number of decimals.

Most languages do have functions called `round`, `ceil`, `floor` or similar ones, but almost all of them round to the nearest integer, so the multiply-round-divide chain *(or divide-round-multiply for rounding to tens, hundreds, thousands...)* is a good pattern to know.

Comment: You could also perform a **bitwise or** with zero, but I have always felt that the `floor` function is easier to read and understand when dealing with real numbers and not, say, bitfields.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the answer. The only thing wrong is where I tapped! I pushed the wrong button and didn't realise until now. Sorry. In the meantime the answer got locked and I can't correct it now. If you could please make a simple edit (anything), the lock will be removed and I will be able to upvote instead. Sorry again.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anders. Nice answer by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can first truncat the part, you do not need.

```js
function c(x, p) {
    return ((x * Math.pow(10, p) | 0) / Math.pow(10, p)).toFixed(p);
}

document.write(c(12.999, 2) + '<br>');
document.write(c(14, 2));
```

Comment: If you're going to make a method you might as well put `toFixed` in there and calculate `100` with `Math.pow` **(almost correct, but there's no reason to calculate the same `Math.pow(10, p)` twice!)**.