# How do I convert string to number and ensure a float type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I used `parseFloat(number)` but it output a int. for example:

```
var num='3.0';
console.log(parseFloat(num)) // 3, not 3.0
```

How do I convert string to number and ensure a float type with a decimal part?

Comment: `3.0` as a number is `3` - end of story - use `toFixed(1)` for chainging a number to a string - but then it's a string not a number

Comment: Also see [How to format a float in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661562/608639) and [JavaScript equivalent to printf/String.Format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610406/608639)

Comment: but i don't want to make the decimal digits fixed to 1.could use some other methods ?

Comment: actually,in my code the number is getting from input.for example,user want to input 3.0.when user input 3.0,the number already turn to 3.

Comment: _“when user input 3.0,the number already turn to 3”_ - yes, and that _is_ the correct numeric representation of the _number_ three. You need to first of all learn to differentiate between the internal representation of a number, and its _formatted output_ for humans. `3.0` is the latter. Now if you say you want this “dynamic”, presumably meaning you want to keep as many decimals as the user entered, even if they are all zeros - then you need to determine that number of decimals _before_ you cast the thing into a number, using the original input while still in its string form.

Comment: @misorude: That would IMO be a valid answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var num = '3.0';
console.log(Number.parseFloat(num).toFixed(1));
```

Comment: but i don't want to make the decimal digits fixed to 1.some other methods could use?

Answer (score 1):

3.0 is 3 it's not wrong

if you do

```
var num='3.1';
console.log(parseFloat(num))//3.1
```

It will display 3.1 so nothing wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

Rounding the value

```js
var num='3.0'
console.log(Math.round(num));
```

Truncateing the value

```js
var num = '3.0';
console.log(Math.floor(num));
console.log(Math.trunc(num))
```

[check this link for more ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)