# Number to Float Conversion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want Conversion from Number to Float in JavaScript

```
function circumference(r) {
  return parseFloat(r);
}
console.log(circumference(4));
```

expected output: 4.00

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. The function `parseFloat` expects a string, but you give it a number. Can you add a little bit of context so that we can understand what you _really_ want to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a float in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661562/how-to-format-a-float-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toFixed()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

```js
function financial(x) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(financial(4));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Number.prototyp.toFixed()` function. You can pass the number of decimal places as the argument.

```js
function circumference(r) {
  return r.toFixed(2);
}
console.log(circumference(4));
```

Answer (score 1):

use parseFloat().toFixed() like this :

```js
var number = parseFloat(4).toFixed(2);
console.log(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a detailed explanation given on [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) with this link having the [example to it](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tofixed).

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n = num.toFixed(2);
console.log(n);
```

Hope this helps.